# Angular 5: Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error in EDGE browser when calling api

Tags: cors, angular5, microsoft-edge, angular-httpclient

I have a angular 5 application which calls a .NET Core 2.0 backend api. Call to the API from the angular service works fine in all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE11) but not in EDGE. In EDGE, i am getting the error

```
Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error.
```

It is a CROSS ORIGIN CALL and Cors has been enabled in the API as below. Right now i am enabling for any origin

```
 services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
                  builder =>
                  {
                      builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                  });
        });
```

And in Configure method

```
app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");
```

It works for all browsers except Edge. Appreciate your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180634/i-get-http-failure-response-for-unknown-url-0-unknown-error-instead-of-actu

Comment: @NagaSaiA, as i have told above, CORS is already enabled and works in all browsers. but not in EDGE :(

Comment: Did  you find a solution ?

Comment: For me it works when I start Fiddler.... When inspecting the requests in DevTools it states it is a "200 OK" response gotten "(from cache)"

Answer (score 0):

Got into the same situation - Angular 6, Edge, same error, other browsers worked fine. Using Fiddler worked as a workaround.

Problem was, that my web was running on localhost and Edge enforced different security rules. Once I've tested the web site on different server, it worked like a charm.

Suppose it might be related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176082/why-are-cors-requests-failing-in-microsoft-edge-but-working-in-other-browsers).

Answer (score 0):

Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error.

This error occure due to edge have advanced security as compared to other browser.
this is actully Cors issue .

that can be solved in two way->

either you can modify header in server side by adding as Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* or

configure the proxy.conf.json inside the angular make sure when you configured the proxy then its won't show the actual server url in broswer console,

for example , your client url as localhost:3000 and server url where api hosted as www.server.com/api/apiname then in browser console it will show like below

localhost:3000/api/apiname