# Post method not working in edge browser, but it is working in other browser like Firefox. internet explorer, chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, https, microsoft-edge

I am struggling with a post method in edge browser, while for same request i am getting response in other browsers like Internet explorer, chrome, Firefox but not in edge.
While i have done lot of analysis but i could not figure out why post request is not working only in edge 
doubt which i have regarding behavior seen in network tabs.
[image]

Please find attached snapshot of network tab(I have removed url and name from screenshot for some policy)
Now question is
1. Why in protocol tab despite of showing HTTPS it is showing "Pending" and in result tab it is also not showing any status just "Pending" and in Initiator tab it is showing "Fetch"

Now i am attaching same request in firefox browser[image]

In this picture we can see complete information of request header and response header

Till this point i find everything right about this request but i don't know why it is not working one doubt that i have is in response header we have

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
```

Do we need to add FETCH also here?
Another doubt i have here that in this project iframe tag is getting used could this be possible cause for this ?

Do i need to make any change in my request header or response header ? or do i need some kind of configuration

I am using angular 7 
Any help is appreciated for any further explanation please comment so that i can clarify
Thanks in advance

Note: While doing some research i found that for edge browser we need to send request in string format which i have already done

Comment: What is the version of Edge you using? Is there any error in console? It sounds like a CORS issue. You could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176082/why-are-cors-requests-failing-in-microsoft-edge-but-working-in-other-browsers). In CORS situation, Edge will only make `GET` requests and make other requests fail. You could try to make a `GET` request or make it out of CORS situation and then to test if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research on my code base i found that there is nothing wrong in code, than after  found, This is open issue on Microsoft edge browser version 42, -Edge marks a request/response as pending indefinitely requests with content-encoding:identity – Issue can be found on Microsoft official website mentioned in below link

[*Link removed, no longer exists*]

Than i tested same request on Dev channel and canary channel of Microsoft edge browser where is it working fine, which means in future release of Microsoft edge this issue will be fixed. Edge for Dev channel and canary channel can be found on below link

[download microsoft edge canary/dev channel](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download)

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.