# Why does a POST request become a GET request in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: reactjs, cors, xmlhttprequest, axios, microsoft-edge

I'm using Axios and React in my frontend app. When I'm trying to send POST request over HTTPS with Axios (xhr, fetch) and faced with the strange issue - my POST request turns into GET in Edge dev tools.

Here is my request:

```
const response = await axios.post(
        config.local + "/api/login/credentials",
        {
          login,
          password
        }
      );
```

Then I tried to dig dipper - created a simple HTTPS server and tried to send POST request from the client.

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt')
};

const PORT = 8188;

function handleRequest(req, res){
    console.log(req.method);
}


const server = https.createServer(options, handleRequest);

server.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log("Server listening on: https://localhost:" + PORT);
});
```

And then, as I understand it, that request does not reach the server.

Here are some links:

[Issue link 1](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1417)

[Issue link 2](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:A7Vkd07ImFwJ:https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11126248/%20&cd=1&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any error in console? You could use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to trace the network traffic and see the details. Also mentioned in the first link you provided, you could also try the two solutions in your GitHub link:

[Solution 1](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1417#issuecomment-521175076):

> My issue is caused by HTTPS; the backend is requiring HTTPS while I send an HTTP post from front side. Now I fixed by changing both to HTTPS.

Or [Solution 2](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1417#issuecomment-523525764):

> I solved it by passing the data in a different format using the "URLSearchParams " class.
>   I had the same problem with:
>   Microsoft Edge 44.18362.267.0
>   Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18362
>   Windows 10
>
> I think the problem is that Edge only supports certain data types in post requests. If you want to use the content-type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' then use URLSearchParams to make it work in Edge and other browsers like Firefox and Chrome. Passing a querystring seems not to work in Edge even if it does in other browsers.
>
> Modifying the original post source code, the result would be:
>
> ```
> import Axios from 'axios'
> import Promise from 'es6-promise'
> Promise.polyfill()
> const URL= 'http://192.168.0.112/account/login/username'
>
> // Use URLSearchParams instead:
> const dataParams = new URLSearchParams()
> dataParams.append('username', 'admin')
> dataParams.append('password', 'admin')
>
> Axios.post(URL, dataParams, {
>   // if you still have problems try more specific options like:
>   // withCredentials: true,
>   // crossdomain: true,
>   // ...
> })
> .then(res=>{
>     console.log(res)
>     }
> )
> .catch(error=>{
>     console.log(error)
>     }
> )
> ```

Aside from that, the issue in your question is usually caused by **[CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#What_requests_use_CORS)**. If you use CORS and request an untrusted origin, then Microsoft Edge will only send the `GET` request and lead to the failure of other requests. You could also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176082/why-are-cors-requests-failing-in-microsoft-edge-but-working-in-other-browsers) to understand why CORS requests fail in Microsoft Edge but work in other browsers. Microsoft Edge also uses [Enhanced Protected Mode](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2012/03/23/understanding-enhanced-protected-mode/), the outcome is that: if the site is trusted, it will make two requests, `OPTIONS` and `GET`, but if it's not trusted, it only makes the `GET` request which causes it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was caused by a self-sign certificate. As soon as I started using normal certificate everything began to work.